# jQuery trying to load a non existent ajax-loader.gif mod-rewrite doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

If you visit this page in Chrome:
http://www.immigrationconsult.org/contact.php

And Inspect Element on the page, go to Console you will see this error:

`GET htt...cms/contact/images/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4`

I followed the instructions here to create a:
http://css-tricks.com/weird-file-requests-and-easing-server-stress-with-htaccess/

I tested to make sure it works, and it does, but not on this specific request. jquery.min.js is the jQuery minified from the makers, I did not change it at all. I used Agent Ransack to deep search for any reference of this in any of my files, the search yielded no results.

I have no idea what to do or how to prevent this issue from happening, this seems like such a small issue, but I can not locate the cause of the problem! Please help.

Comment: Check whether 'ajax-loader.gif' file is in the  'http://www.immigrationconsult.org/cms/contact/images/' folder

Comment: The problem is that this jquery.min.js is loaded on every page on my site, so am I supposed to create a dummy images folder in every directory and put the image there? I need to modify the javascript, but, I don't know where the request is coming from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it was really a misdirection by Chrome. The plugin at fault was jQuery Coda-Slider. Because it was JS compressed, Agent Ransack couldn't find the string... lesson learned...

Answer (score 0):

You clearly don't have the ajax-loader.gif file in the correct directory, or at least your ajax script is looking the wrong place.

you can either modify the java script to point to the right location or you can just put the file in the correct location, i would choose the latter.

I have had these errors my self with JQuery, where some icons didn't get loaded, just had to put them in the correct folder and it worked.

But if you use googles jquery libs, all resources should get loaded automagic as well. Like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.7.2");
  google.load(etc..);
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that this jquery.min.js is loaded on every page on my site, so am I supposed to create a dummy images folder in every directory and put the image there? I need to modify the javascript, but, I don't know where the request is coming from...

Comment: my guess is you have a header.php which you include for all pages as it should be the same for every page, and include your java scripts there? or depends on your folder structure maybe? you have each page in a new folder and the paths a re relative to that *.php file?

Comment: Yes, I heave a header.php that gets loaded with every page... the pages are actually served by WordPress and don't actually exist, neither do the folders, for example, I have no /contact/ folder... it's all done by wordpress rewriting...

Comment: i see you are using http://www.immigrationconsult.org/jquery.min.js for source, what happens if you just use relative path like just "jquery.min.js" or even just use googles jquery?

Comment: Thanks, for helping. I get this error when doing it above way: `Uncaught Error: Module: 'jquery' with version '1.7.2' not found! jsapi:16`

I also tried just `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` but I still get the original missing ajax-loader.gif error

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the entire zip file from their website: http://jquerymobile.com/download/. After you unzip it, you will find the js file, the CSS and a folder called "images", all of which need to be present locally.